# Why don't Python's built-in functions have code objects?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python, so this might be an obvious question, but I searched everywhere (including the documentation), and I can't seem to get the code object of a builtin function in python. For example, in my PyCharm editor, when I type this code, it does not detect any errors:

```
print(getattr.__code__)
```

But when I run it, it gives an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'
```

Is there a reason why built-in functions in python do not have a code object, and is this a bug in my IDE?

I am using Python 3.

Comment: To detect errors the IDE would have to execute the code. It can't know whether the code would be destructive so won't do it.

Comment: But then would the "builtin_function_or_method" still have a code object?

Comment: If the object is implemented in C then it doesn't have a `__code__` attribute. Many built-ins are C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built-in functions don't have code objects because they're implemented in C, not in Python. Only Python functions have code objects, because code objects are compiled Python byte-code. [Exploring Python Code Objects](http://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects.html) is a good explanation of code objects.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the brief explanation.